# Why is an API response.json array not iterable in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte

I've been working on a simple nutrition tracking app as a final project for CS50, using Svelte and Firebase to make it fully functional. I've run into a problem in the frontend, as I'm using API calls to retrieve nutrition information. The API returns a json array which I would use to present options to the user and log information as they select. However, when I try to iterate over this array to make an option for each, I receive an error stating that it is not an array-type object.

I decided to reproduce the code in REPL, and achieved good results. The below code logs the full 50 items as an array, as per the API's documentation.

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    let foodList;
    async function loadList() {
        let list = await fetch('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/list?dataType=Foundation&api_key=DEMO_KEY');
        let foodList = await list.json();
        console.log(foodList);
    }
        
    onMount(() => {
    loadList();
    });
```

I receive this abbreviated output:

`(50) [ {…} ,{…} ,{…} ,{…} ,{…} , … ]`

However, when trying to iterate over this array, I receive the error:

`{#each} only iterates over array-like objects.`

using below code:

```
{#await loadList}
    <p>
        Loading...
</p>
{:then foodList}
    {#each foodList as item}
        <p>
            {item.description}
    </p>
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

I would appreciate any help, as I feel like I'm missing something fundamental that might be obvious to some others.

Comment: Change `console.log(foodList)` to `return foodList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#await` is trying to check the function, not a promise.

Could you try this?

```
<script>
    async function loadFoodList() {
        const res = await fetch('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/list?dataType=Foundation&api_key=DEMO_KEY');
        const foodList = await res.json();

        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("Something's wrong");
        }

        return foodList;
    }
    
    const foodListPromise = loadFoodList();
</script>

{#await foodListPromise}
    <p>Loading...</p>
{:then foodList}
    {#each foodList as item}
        <p>{item.description}</p>
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

You can read more here: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks